# Parsing local XML files using Ruby on Rails 4.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xml, xml-parsing, ruby-on-rails-4

I have folder that contains many sub folders with xml files that have information on League of Legends champions. My end goal is to have an index page that lists all League of Legends champions and a show page with details on each one.

I tried doing this before I learned Rails and this is what I have so far.

---

```
File.open("champion_list.txt", "w") do |file_name|
    File.open("champions.txt", "r").each do |folder_name|
      folder_name = folder_name.strip
      xml = File.open("LoLChampions/data/#{folder_name}/champion.xml").read
      file_name.write(xml)
    end
end
```

Line-by-line breakdown...

```
#open the list of every champion
#read each champion individually and do this to each one
#strips the individual champions of useless text including a ton of /n /br's
#reads the champion file inside of it's folder which is named after the name of each champion that has been grabbed from the textfile.
#each champion has a folder named the name of the champion and each champion folder contains images of the champion and a champion.xml file.
```

---

Ideally I want to parse this by hand, but i'm open to use other existing libraries. I mentioned using JSON.

Second, the subfolder for each champion contains images inside and I'm wondering if I'm going to need to extract every image and put it inside the assets/images folder.

Third, where do all of the champion xml files go in Rails 4.0

This is a huge question, I know, but feel free to only answer it in parts.

Thanks,
Ian

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. To parse XML, I'd go with Nokogiri http://nokogiri.org/
2. You don't necessarily need to move images under assets (or public). You can also create route and action for those images and use send_file, see http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/DataStreaming/send_file
3. I'm not sure if I understood this part. Rails certainly does not have a convention for location of champion xml files. Pick a place that feels convenient and remember to document it to README so that other developers (or future you) knows where to look for them.

Comment: Thanks! I have all of the xml data in one large file. Now I just need to figure out how to display it in a list in my index.html.erb